# Dynamic Stage Variables in AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

How can I set stageVariables via request headers or query string 
parameters in API Gateway?

I have added a stageVariable to the lambda function name in the integration request. When I set the stage variable fixed in the stage this does work.
However, when I try to set the variable via a query string I get a server error.

How can I set a lambda version in an API request dynamically?

Comment: did you able to find out any solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

I think Stage Variables are just that - they vary on stage, and nothing else.  If there's a way of mapping a query parameter into a stage variable I'd like to know about it - but I think it's not possible.